# How can i prevent standard user from accessing terminal?

Tags: command-line, permissions, users, gnome-terminal, restricted-access

How can i prevent/restrict standard users from accessing terminal in ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-i386 ?

I need to prevent standard users and administrators(not root account) in Ubuntu user accounts from accessing terminal.I am doing a R&D for "ubuntu Desktop management"that is to be done through our Network monitoring software

Comment: ... What's wrong with using the terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking to ban users that you allow to log in from using a terminal for security reasons, it does not make much sense. "The Terminal" is  a tool that will allow you to perform certain actions that you have rights to do. If you take away the right to run "the terminal" (which is actually just another program), the right to perform these actions is not taken away. A user could simply run another program (downloaded?) to perform these actions.

Now if you want to block other users (non-standard I would call them) from loging in at all (be it via the normal method, or via 'the terminal'), you could change the shell line in `/etc/passwd` to something like `/sbin/nologin`: this user will not be able to log in.

Example (I can't stress enough that this is probably not what you want for `normal` users, but it is the only way I can see use for the question. proceed with care)

```
nologinuserx:111:123:description,,,:PATH:/bin/false
normaluser:1123:1123:,,,:/home/myname:/bin/bash
```

I'm currently using `/bin/false` instead of `nologin` it seems, but that's how it looks

As @gertvdijk mentions in the comments, you could (should?) do this with the `chsh` (CHange SHell) command like so:

```
$ sudo chsh -s /usr/sbin/nologin username
```

Comment: Which line in /etc/passwd are you talking about? I don't have any line in /etc/passwd named shell

Comment: I understand what you meant.I need to do implement desktop policy for Ubuntu desktops in our company

Comment: Be aware that editing this line is NOT applicable for regular users. You would do that for the users like `www-data` that should never be used to log in.

Comment: That's great. If you can, add the reasons or some more explanation to your question: it will be better for future googlers. Also, if this works, consider accepting it as a valid answer (use the checkmark) and/or give it an upvote.

Comment: I need to prevent standard users and administrators(not root account) in Ubuntu user accounts from accessing terminal.I am doing a R&D for "ubuntu Desktop management"that is to be done through our Network monitoring software

Comment: You misunderstood me: I meant edit the question. I'll add this for you, but please review it (the question) and add whatever you think might clear things up the best.

Comment: Why not just use `chsh` for changing the login shell, rather than editing the passwd file manually?

Comment: $ sudo chsh -s /usr/sbin/nologin username is easier to implement .How to revert the setting using the same command?

Comment: set it back to what it was, for instance 'bash'